# What is necessary to build a Linux .so library with C++ in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, dynamic-library

I just have my Linux-version of project set up (by default I was compiling to Windows). I downloaded Visual Studio extension to Linux cross-compiling. I didn't do anything like that before and it asks me for Linux Build Server. I guess I should create a VM for Linux based system and then pass hostname, password, user etc. I just want to be able to build my dynamic library! I don't want to download 10 GB Debian just for one small library. Do you guys some other easy way to build it? Maybe there is this kind of server available.

I don't want to execute it or something. I just need to port my .dll plugin to .so plugin for Linux web server.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look: http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/linux/libraries/

Answer (score 0):

You need a Linux system of some sort with g++ to compile it, gdb+gdbserver if you want to debug it, ssh to remote into it and bash to execute commands from VCLinux.

The obvious way to do this is to spin up a VM with your choice of Linux distro. Debian download is around 4GB and a minimal install will fit on a 6GB virtual disk.

But there are alternatives. VClinux will run against WSL ([there's a how to here](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSLinux/issues/42)). A Raspberry PI is $40 and Raspbian is Debian. And an Azure Linux VM is cheap.